# RegEx lookaround to find Start>Foo where Foo bar never appeared

Tags: regex, unix

I apologize for the horrendous topic name but I couldn't think of a way to further abstract this question. I have been wracking my brain trying to figure out the RegEx syntax for this problem and pouring over questions about lookarounds, but to no avail.

I want to return results from **start** to the first instance of **foo** (unless it is immediately followed by **bar**) *OR* the end of the file. Additionally, if **foo bar** appears before **foo !bar** or end of file, I do not want anything returned.

Below is what I have been working with so far. I may be completely off track; however, I am definitely looking to stay within RegEx unless it's completely impossible to do. I've already solved this problem using not RegEx, but I'm trying to expand my understanding of RegEx as it bothers me I couldn't work out how to do this search. Also the RegEx implementation I am using is PCRE.

Currently this RegEx will report regardless of whether **foo bar** appears as the first **foo** or not. I feel as though I am missing some simple solution but using negative lookbehind and other methods I've not been able to get the search to not return anything if **foo bar** appears as the first **foo** while also returning cases where **foo !bar** appears either on its own, before **foo bar**, or where no **foo** appears at all.

**Current Search:**

```
start(?:\n|\r|.)*?(?:\Z|foo(?! +bar))
```

Here's three example files and what I want the search to return delineated by single quotes.

**Example 1:** Should not return anything.

```
Start
     Text
     Text
     Foo Bar
     Foo Doo
```

**Example 2:** Should return text between quotes.

```
'Start
    Text
    Text
    Foo Doo
    Foo' Bar
```

**Example 3:** Should return text between quotes.

```
'Start
    Text
    Text'
```

Thanks!

Comment: You say "should return", what exactly should example 2 and 3 return?

Comment: Sorry about the lack of clarity there, I added single quotes around the text I expect to be returned by the RegEx query. Obviously the quotes are not intended to be part of the file.

Comment: Why in example 2, the match ends after the second `Foo` (which is followed by `Bar`), since it is supposed to match until the first instance of `Foo` not followed by `Bar`?

Comment: This was just the way my search as I had written it was working at the time. The solution you suggested resulted in a better match. Either would have been acceptable.

Comment: for what you posted - example 2 - use this crazy pattern   `(Start(?:(?:(?:[\s\S](?!Foo Bar))*?Foo(?!\s+Bar)[\s\S]*?)*[\s\S]Foo(?= Bar)|(?![\s\S]*Foo\s+Bar)[\s\S]*?(?:Foo|$)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need first to prevent "foo" in the content after "start". To do that you can use several ways. A well known way is to use: `(?:(?!foo).)*` *(you ensure that each character you match is not the begining of the word you don't want)*. However this way isn't very performant in general since a lookahead is tested at each position.

An other way consists to use the first character of the word you want to avoid and to build a negative character class with it. So you can describe the content like this:

```
(?>[^f]+|f(?!oo))*
```

The advantage of this approach is to limit the amount of lookahead tests that are only performed when the first letter "f" is encountered. The inconvenient, is that you need to hardcode the letter and the other part of the word in the pattern or to build the pattern dynamically with substrings of the word. (`sprintf` can be handy in this case)

Then the whole pattern becomes:

```
start(?>[^f]+|f(?!oo))*(?:foo(?! bar)|\z)
```

**pattern description:**

```
start
(?>               # open an atomic group
    [^f]+         # all characters except f (one or more times)
  |               # OR
    f(?!oo)       # f not followed by oo
)*                # repeat the group zero or more times
(?:              
    foo(?! bar)   # "foo" not followed by a space and "bar"
  |               # OR
    \z            # end of the string
)
```

Comment: This worked flawlessly and the explanation was easy to understand, thank you very much! One question: I actually tried using the less performant solution you suggested on my own and was unable to get it to work as a multiline search. I assume this is because of the "." character, is there a way to include \n and \r without breaking the syntax of: `start(?:(?!foo).)*(?:foo(?! bar)|\z)` ? Obviously I plan to use the more performant solution but wondering for my own knowledge. Great breakdown on how to make the search more efficient!

Comment: @DouglasMiller: To make work the other way, you need to allow the dot to match newlines with the s modifier. Take a look here: http://regex101.com/r/mV5cK9/1

Comment: I don't believe setting the dot character to match newline is available in pcregrep which is where I was using this RegEx. I was able to reproduce that functionality originally with dot matches newline enabled in various other environments but spent forever trying to figure out how to add return and newline characters without breaking it. Glad to finally have a solution that is more efficient and works, thanks!

Comment: @DouglasMiller: With pcregrep you can use inline modifiers like this: `(?s)start(?:(?!foo).)*(?:foo(?! bar)|\z)` *(you can put it everywhere in the pattern, but before the dot)*. You switch off the modifier with `(?-s)`

Answer (score 0):

It's a little messy but here we go:

`((?(?=.*Foo Bar)Start.*?Foo(?= Bar(?![\s]*$)(?!.*?foo (?!bar)))|.*))`

NOTE: You would need to enable the 's' modifier to enable dot to match newline.
The output is in the first capturing group (\1). The detailed explanation is at the bottom.

As a general comment, it will be probably easier to do conditionals(if/esle) stuff inside the codes than in the regex. It will also be more readable and easier to maintain.

Btw, you can try this regex [here](http://regex101.com/r/cD5pA0/4).

Hope it helps! :D

```
(                                  # first capturing group
 (?                                # if conditional
   (?=.*Foo Bar)                   # if(foo bar exists in this file), using look ahead
     Start.*?Foo                   # Match Start to the first instance of Foo
        (?=                        # Look ahead
          Bar                      # Match space and Bar
            (?![\s]*$)             # Match !(white spaces and end of line)
              (?!.*?foo (?!bar)))  # Match !(foo !bar)          
   |                               # else
     .*                            # Match everything
 )    
)
```

Comment: Oh well it depends on what is your interpretation of end of file. If you wanna match white space as well simply add this `[\s]*` inside `(?![\s]*$)`. See example [here](http://regex101.com/r/cD5pA0/4)